# Two datePublished for LiveBlogPosting

Tags: seo, blog, schema.org, rich-snippets, dates

Based on the information below, I understand having a `datePublished` for the actual post on the WordPress blog index page, but it required a `datePublished` for the actual blog.

**How does Google treats the datePublished at the `LiveBlogPosting` level (not the `liveBlogUpdate` level)?**

Is it the date that the blog was published? Is it the date of the most recent post that was published? Is it the last date the blog was modified? Or maybe something else?

[image: Google Structured Data Testing Tool: LiveBlogPosting check with 2 errors]

Comment: Here is an answer that may help some: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85857/posting-old-content-on-a-new-website-which-date-to-use/85876#85876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Schema.org’s perspective:

- The [`datePublished` property](http://schema.org/datePublished) for the [`LiveBlogPosting`](http://schema.org/LiveBlogPosting) gives the publication date of the blog post, i.e., when it was first published, typically saying "something happened" and then the live blogging begins.
- The [`datePublished` property](http://schema.org/datePublished) for each [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) referenced with the [`liveBlogUpdate` property](http://schema.org/liveBlogUpdate) gives the publication date of that update.
- Both have nothing to do with the date of the last modification. This can be given in the [`dateModified` property](http://schema.org/dateModified):

  - For the `LiveBlogPosting` you could use `dateModified` each time another update gets posted, but that would be redundant (as it would be the same date as the `datePublished` of the newest update). I would only use it for modifications that happen after the live blogging stopped.
  - For the referenced `BlogPosting` items, you could use `dateModified` if the update, after it got published, gets modified (but that’s probably rather uncommon, as typically a new update gets posted with a correction instead).

From Google’s perspective, it wouldn’t make any sense not to follow Schema.org’s definitions. However, they don’t seem to have a Rich Snippet (or similar product) that makes use of `LiveBlogPosting` (or do they?).

Comment: I don't even have to read the answer to up-vote it. Not when it is from you!!  Not with your expertise.

Comment: From what I was reading LiveBlogPosting, it is used in the same was that Article is used, just specific to blogging. Thanks for the helpful answer!