# Can dateModified be unset on a Schema.org Article, if so when should it be set for the first time?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, articles, dates

I am trying to understand what the various dates mean in [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article) from [Schema.org](http://schema.org/).

From what I can understand is the following:

- `dateCreated` is when the writer first starting with the article. Nothing has been made public yet for reading. `dateCreated` can be earlier or the same as `datePublished`, but not later.
- `datePublished` is when the writer is finished with the article and has made it available online for reading.
- `dateModified` is when the article is modified.

The above is my opinion. What is the general opinion regarding this?

If an article has not be edited will it then contain nothing/null for `dateModified`? The reason why I ask is because when you run your code through the structured data testing tool it says that `dateModified` is not required but recommended. How can it be recommended for articles that have not been edited from their original source? Should `dateModified` then be the same as `datePublished` just so that the red error message can go away? Or shouldn't I worry about it and treat it as a warning?

When is `dateModified` set for the first time? After `dateCreated` or after `datePublished`?

Comment: Related (not duplicates): [Two datePublished for LiveBlogPosting](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/86103/17633) · [Posting old content on a new website. Which date to use?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/85857/17633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would omit the [`dateModified`](http://schema.org/dateModified) property as long as the article is not modified after publication. However, that’s more of a philosophical decision than a technical one. Consumers should be able to handle it both ways if they are inclined to do so:

- **If `datePublished` == `dateModified`:** The article was never modified after publication (or it was modified, but the author didn’t update the `dateModified` value).
- **If no `dateModified`:** The article was never modified after publication (or it was modified, but the author didn’t provide the `dateModified` property).

Google doesn’t give more information in their [Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) documentation, but in their [Top Stories with AMP](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories) documentation, they say (bold emphasis mine):

> The date and time the article was most recently modified, in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If the article has never been modified, **you can omit this property or use the same date as datePublished**.

I guess it’s safe to assume that they will handle it in the same way for their other search result features (e.g., the Article Rich Snippet), too.

Answer (score 4):

dateModified always has a potential value (there's always something you could set) and can be equal to or later than dateCreated. ‘Creating is modifying’ and a good example of this is the filesystem on whatever OS you're using — creating a file sets the dateCreated and the dateModified together, then subsequent edits change the dateModified.

Whether or not you count publishing as a modification or not is up to you, but I encourage you to be consistent with this. In my case, I do count publishing as a modification, so when publishing I set datePublished and update dateModified.

Comment: I will consider your recommendation.

Comment: I don't understand "should never not have a potential value".

Comment: @TRiG See edit?

Comment: That works for me. And, on reflection, I do understand what you were saying, but I think it's clearer now.